# Django, Postgres DateRangeField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm using the range fields feature for postgrest in Django, and I made a model in which the date from and date to are stored in a range for checking if it overlaps, but there is a problem, if the date from and date to are the same date the model get stored like this.

```
DateRange(empty=True)
```

I tested that this DateRange feature can store a range that has the same date at start and at the end if i test it in the shell, but, in the model when it gets saved it just save it like i just mentioned before.

What can I do?

Edit:

This is the code.

```
class Reservaciones(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Reservaciones"

    def random_string():
        return str(
            randint(10000, 999999999)
        )

    fechas_semana = [
        timezone.localdate() + timedelta(days=i)
        for i in range (
            0 - date.today().weekday(),
            7 - date.today().weekday()
        )
    ]
    fecha_vie = fechas_semana[4]

    ESTADOS= (
        ("Pendiente", "Pendiente"),
        ("Reservado", "Reservado"),
        ("Usado", "Usado"),
    )
    nucleo = models.ForeignKey(
        Nucleo,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        null = False,
        blank = False,
        limit_choices_to = {
            'estado': "Activo"
        }        
    )
    cabaña = models.ForeignKey(
        Cabaña,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        null = False,
        blank = False,
        limit_choices_to = {
            'estado': "Activo"
        }
    )
    estado = models.CharField(
        max_length = 10,
        choices = ESTADOS,
        default = "Pendiente",
        null = False,
        blank = False
    )
    fecha_desde = models.DateField(
        null = True,        
        blank = True,
    )       
    fecha_hasta = models.DateField(
        null = True,        
        blank = True,
    )       
    fechas = DateRangeField(
    )   
    fecha_exp = models.DateField(
        null = False,        
        blank = False,
    )    
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        null = False,
        blank = False
    )
    codigo = models.CharField(
        max_length = 10,
        editable = False,
        unique = True,
        default = random_string,        
        null = False,
        blank = False
    )
    envio = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now = False,
        auto_now_add = True
    )
    envio_dia = models.DateField(
        auto_now = False,
        auto_now_add = True
    )    
    actualizado = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now = True,
        auto_now_add = False
    )    
    observacion = models.TextField(
        null = True,        
        blank = True
    )
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.codigo

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fechas = DateRange(self.fecha_desde, self.fecha_hasta)
        super(Reservaciones, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):

        if Reservaciones.objects.filter(fechas__overlap=DateRange(self.fecha_desde - timedelta(days=1), self.fecha_hasta + timedelta(days=1))
        ).filter(
            nucleo = self.nucleo
        ).filter(
            cabaña=self.cabaña
        ).exclude(
            codigo = self.codigo
        ).difference(
            Reservaciones.objects.filter(estado="Pendiente", fecha_exp__lt=timezone.localdate())
        ).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Ya existe una reservación para esta cabaña en las fechas que haz seleccionado.")  
        elif self.fecha_desde == self.fecha_hasta and Reservaciones.objects.filter(
            fecha_desde=self.fecha_desde
        ).filter(
            fecha_hasta=self.fecha_hasta
        ).filter(
            nucleo = self.nucleo
        ).filter(
            cabaña=self.cabaña
        ).exclude(
            codigo = self.codigo
        ).difference(
            Reservaciones.objects.filter(estado="Pendiente", fecha_exp__lt=timezone.localdate())
        ).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Ya existe una reservación para esta cabaña en las fechas que haz seleccionado.")  
        elif self.fecha_hasta < self.fecha_desde:  
            raise ValidationError("La fecha maxima de la reservación no puede ser inferior a la fecha de inicio de la misma.") 
        elif self.cabaña_id not in list(Cabaña.objects.filter(nucleo=self.nucleo, id=self.cabaña_id).values_list('id', flat=True)):         
            raise ValidationError("Esta cabaña no existe en este nucleo.")
```

This work just perfect to validate the dates.

But for this busines logic, i just let the users choose from the form the dates and room (Cabaña) that are not occupied

```
def ReservacionCargarCabañaView(request):
    nucleo = request.GET.get('nucleo')
    fecha_desde = request.GET.get('fecha_desde')
    fecha_hasta = request.GET.get('fecha_hasta')    
    fecha_desde = datetime.strptime(fecha_desde, '%Y-%m-%d') - timedelta(days=1)   
    fecha_hasta = datetime.strptime(fecha_hasta, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=1)  
    fecha_desde = date(fecha_desde.year, fecha_desde.month, fecha_desde.day)
    fecha_hasta = date(fecha_hasta.year, fecha_hasta.month, fecha_hasta.day)    

    cabaña = Cabaña.objects.filter(
        nucleo=nucleo
    ).exclude(
        estado="Inactivo"
    ).exclude(
        id__in=Reservaciones.objects.filter(fechas__overlap=DateRange(fecha_desde, fecha_hasta)
        ).exclude(
            id__in=Reservaciones.objects.filter(estado="Pendiente", fecha_exp__lt=timezone.localdate()).values_list('id')
        ).values_list(
        'cabaña'
        )
    ).order_by(
        'cabaña'
    ) 

    return render(
        request,
        'socios/formulario/cabaña_opciones_lista.html',
        {
            'cabaña': cabaña,
        }
    )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNQNY.png)

But if for example i choose in fecha desde and fecha hasta the same date to make a reservation for a single date, the form does not hide the rooms (Cabañas).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcuqD.png)

The form ajax list does not hide the "Cabaña 1" because that reservation made for date 18/4/2018 has a DateRange empty has i stated before.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Sorry, I just added some more information in my problem